# Swedish characters (åäö) in Vim & Nano

Tags: vim, encoding, utf-8, character, nano

When I'm using Vim or Nano in Mac OS X Lion, the Swedish characters "ÅÄÖ" show up as "Ã¥Ã¤Ã¶". It works fine in Terminal.

I've added this line to my .vimrc:

```
set encoding=utf8
```

If I run **locale** in Terminal it shows:

```
LANG="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You say, "show"? They show like that when you type them in insert mode? Apart from encoding=utf8, what fonts are you using? set guifont? set printfont? Do you have anything set up under set fileencoding? and set fileencodings? ... (i'm not swedish, but trying to help from my (similar) experiences)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. Yes, when I type them in insert mode. I've tried setting both fileencoding and fileencodings to "utf8" but it doesn't help. I use the same font as in Terminal, Monaco (which has support for åäö). Strange...

Comment: (okey, next guess ...) If you set the encoding to cp1250 which from what I can see supports swedish characters (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250) does that make anything different? ... The irony in this whole story was that just a few days ago, I was trying to print mine (Croatian) characters, and instead what I got, was something looking exactly like the ones you're looking for :\

Comment: I've tried that encoding and ISO8859-1 as well. ISO8859-1 gives me the characters but with spaces around them. I should be able to use UTF-8, right?

Comment: Yup, you *should*. Let me share my experiences (Croatian characters, same problem): ... had enc=utf8 ... could write them, but when printed I get garbage. I then switched to cp1250 or 1252, all problems gone. Have no idea why, smarter people don't know either (problem with dealing with this kinda problems is that very few people are from Sweden/Croatia/... so they don't encounter them). Generally, the solution is somewhere in encoding/fileencoding/fileencodings/guifont/printfont/ and the options from your vim (:version) +postscript and .... +printer (I believe).

Comment: Only it's hard to help  much when I can't test it from your point of view. Leave the question open for some time more; there are a few vimmers in here much more knowledgeable who may be able to give better suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution here: [see thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185707/how-do-i-paste-non-ascii-characters-into-vim)

"The solution was to uncheck the "Escape non-ASCII input" checkbox in the Advanced tab of the Terminal.app settings."

Thanks **Idigas** and **progo** for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Could be your `termencoding` needs to be set properly.

Comment: I added set termencoding=utf8 in .vimrc but it still doesn't work.