# How do I fix pasting unicode characters in vim from system clipboard on OSX?

Tags: vim, unicode, clipboard, neovim

I'm having an issue where, when I copy from or paste into vim using the `*` register, unicode characters seem to be mangled in different ways depending on the source and target of the copy-paste. Pasting into the buffer using <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in `INSERT` mode pastes what I would expect.

For example copying from vim to TextEdit produces multiple characters for each source character…

```
in vim:
“I am copied from « vim » ⇒ TextEdit”

in TextEdit:
‚ÄúI am copied from ¬´ vim ¬ª ‚áí TextEdit‚Äù
```

…and copying from TextEdit to vim produces something else

```
in TextEdit:
“I am copied from TextEdit ⇒ « vim »”

in vim:
<d2>I am copied from TextEdit ? <c7> vim <c8><d3>
```

The same issue shows up for other applications as well, not just TextEdit.

A couple questions:

1. I'm assuming the characters that show up in TextEdit are a decomposition of the source unicode characters, but what are the `<d2>` characters that show up in vim?
2. Does anyone know the source of the issue and how to resolve it such that copy-pasting between vim and OSX apps works as expected?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185707/how-do-i-paste-non-ascii-characters-into-vim maybe?

Comment: @JiříPospíšil thanks for the link! Unfortunately that's not quite it — the answer there makes it so that ⌘+V will paste into the terminal correctly, but this issue is specifically with using the `*` register.

Comment: What does running `:echo &fenc &enc` produce?

Comment: @bk2204 `utf-8 utf-8`